# aop with spring 2.5 without Aspect J

Tags: spring, spring-aop, spring-2.5

I am working in a old project with spring 2.5.Application context starts with 


.

I need to implment logging using aop I need to log each and every class's method.
tried this link :
http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/aop/4769-apply-jdkregexpmethodpointcut-to-multiple-beans-how.But didnt work.
and some more options.(but i felt this is taking me some where)
Also, I cant use xsd so i cant use aop namespace.i cant use aspect j as well

Please guide me on how can i achieve this what should be point cut as I have tried . and * as pattern and bean names with the point cut.

Comment: starts with  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE beans PUBLIC "-//SPRING//DTD BEAN 2.0//EN" "http://www.springframework.org/dtd/spring-beans-2.0.dtd">

Comment: Is it spring 2.0 or 2.5? DTD says 2.0, while your tag says 2.5... Share some details for "didnt' work" !

Comment: advice was not applied ,i didnt get any errors

Answer (score 0):

**spring.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

    <bean id="debugInterceptor" class="test.DebugInterceptor" />

    <bean id="testBean" class="test.TestBean" />

    <bean class="org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.BeanNameAutoProxyCreator">
      <property name="beanNames" value="*" />
      <property name="interceptorNames">
        <list>
          <value>debugInterceptor</value>
        </list>
      </property>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

**TestBean**

```
package test;

public class TestBean {

    public void foo() {
        System.out.println("foo");
    }

    void bar() {
        System.out.println("bar");
    }

}
```

**DebugInterceptor**

```
package test;

import org.aopalliance.intercept.MethodInterceptor;
import org.aopalliance.intercept.MethodInvocation;

public class DebugInterceptor implements MethodInterceptor {

    public Object invoke(MethodInvocation invocation) throws Throwable {
        System.out.println("Before: invocation=[" + invocation + "]");
        Object rval = invocation.proceed();
        System.out.println("Invocation returned");
        return rval;
    }

}
```

**AopTest**

```
package test;

import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;

public class AopTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext ap = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("classpath:spring.xml");
        TestBean bean = (TestBean)ap.getBean("testBean");
        bean.foo();
        bean.bar();
    }

}
```